# Apache CXF timezone for date

Tags: java, datetime, soap, cxf

I have received a wsdl from one of our customer and generated the java code (using apache cxf 3.0.3). Using soap ui I can send requests and receive proper response against customer backend.

In the request there are several fields defined as datetime. What conversion uses apache cxf to handle datetime types ? Is it following ISO 8601 with UTC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CXF 2.5.10 the dateformat with utc was yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z. Think that maybe they use jodatime